# How to get discord bot to read embed

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I understand how a discord bot can read a regular user inputed message and respond using

```
if(message.content.toLowerCase().includes('cyber'))
    message.channel.send("Key Word Detected ");
```

But it won't read the message if it is an embed. Please help me change that to look for the keyword in a embed message and elicit a response from the bot.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for SO to write code for you. Could you show what you've tried to change within those lines, and explain why it didn't work? Maybe link the part of the docs you're trying to deal with

Comment: I tried changing the code to look like `if(embed.Message.content.toLowerCase().includes('cyber'))
    message.channel.send("Key Word Detected ");`

`if(embed.content.toLowerCase().includes('cyber'))
    message.channel.send("Key Word Detected ");`

nothing seems to be working and everything I've looked up seems to not have any solution to my problem

Comment: Are you sure that embed.Message exists ? For me, after looking at [this guide](https://anidiots.guide/first-bot/using-embeds-in-messages), it seems like an embed is a list of fields, so I would do something like 
`fields = message.embed.fields;
len = fields.length;
for var i in range(len){
if fields[i].value.contains('cyber')...`

Answer (score 4):

The text in a [`MessageEmbed`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed) can be in `author`, `description`, `footer`, `message.content` and `title`. They can also be inside every filed, so might want to check for all that stuff.
Here's a little function you could use (I know it seems a mess but it's just because there are a lot of logical operators):

```js
/*
      message {Discord.Message}: the message you want to search in
      target {string}: the string you're looking for
      {
        caseSensitive {boolean}: whether you want the search to be case case-sensitive
        author {boolean}: whether you want to search in the author's name
        description {boolean}: whether you want to search in the description
        footer {boolean}: whether you want to search in the footer
        title {boolean}: whether you want to search in the title
        fields {boolean}: whether you want to search in the fields
      }
     */
function findInMessage(message, target, {
  caseSensitive = false,
  author = false,
  description = true,
  footer = true,
  title = true,
  fields = true
}) {
  if (!target || !message) return null;
  let str = caseSensitive ? target : target.toLowerCase();

  if ((caseSensitive && message.content.includes(str)) ||
    (!caseSensitive && message.content.toLowerCase().includes(str))) return true;

  for (let embed of message.embeds) {
    if ((caseSensitive && (
        (author && embed.author.includes(str)) ||
        (description && embed.description.includes(str)) ||
        (footer && embed.footer.includes(str)) ||
        (title && embed.title.includes(str)))) ||
      (!caseSensitive && (
        (author && embed.author.toLowerCase().includes(str)) ||
        (description && embed.description.toLowerCase().includes(str)) ||
        (footer && embed.footer.toLowerCase().includes(str)) ||
        (title && embed.title.toLowerCase().includes(str))))
    ) return true;

    if (fields)
      for (let field of embed.fields) {
        if ((caseSensitive && [field.name, field.value].includes(str)) ||
          (!caseSensitive && [field.name.toLowerCase(), field.value.toLowerCase()].includes(str))) return true;
      }
  }

  return false;
}
```

The functions returns `true` when finds the word you put in, `false` when it doesn't find it and `null` when one of the non-optional arguments is missing.
You can use it like this:

```js
if (findInMessage(message, 'cyber')) message.channel.send("Key word detected.");
```

There are some instructions at the top, hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

This should be it, checking for all embeds in the message too

```
if(message.content.toLowerCase().includes('cyber'))
    message.channel.send("Key Word Detected ");
else {
    for(var i = 0; i < message.embeds.length; i++) {
        if(message.embeds[i].title.includes("cyber") || message.embeds[i].title.includes("cyber")) {
            message.channel.send("Detected");
            break;
    }
}
```