# Discord.js Read A Field In a Message

Tags: discord.js

this is what the embedded message looks like

[image]

I got an external software to send an embedded message to this discord server, now I want my discord.js to read the Username how should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the main chunk of the code you'll need. This is based off of [Federico Grandi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53201455/how-to-get-discord-bot-to-read-embed/53206377).

This is a function that takes in an embed as an argument and based off of that embed, searches in the fields (as that's what it seems like the bot is placing the username in), and then returns the answer, or username of the person who signed up.

```js
function findInMessage(embed) {
    for (let field of embed.fields) {
        if (field.name == 'Username') {
            return field.value;
        }
    }
}
```

You'll still need to implement a section where the bot detects the embed and then proceeds to trigger the function, and then posts the username, but that should be simple enough.

Example:

[image: Example]

Comment: Are you able to add me on discord? I got a few questions Jerryx#5671

Comment: Okay I've just sent you a request.