# Is there a way to get an author of different interaction?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm discovering [`discord.js`](https://discord.js.org/#/) library and specifically bot development to myself and I've been stuck with an idea I have no clue how to implement so far.

In a verification channel I have a message with a button (customId of which is `requestVerification`) which in its turn shows a `modal`. The data of the input of this modal is later sent to the requests channel in a form of an `embed message` with `two buttons` (first one is for approving, second one is for denying).

I want these buttons to directly interact with a user that NOT triggered a button click, but the user who actually filled in the inputs in the modal.

The code looks something like this:

`verificationButtonEvent.js` (here I'm showing the modal to a user)

```js
const {
  Events, ActionRowBuilder, ModalBuilder, TextInputBuilder, TextInputStyle, EmbedBuilder, PermissionsBitField
} = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  name: Events.InteractionCreate, execute(interaction) {
    if (!interaction.isButton()) return;

    switch (interaction.customId) {
      case "requestVerification": {
        // create the modal
        const verificationModal = new ModalBuilder()
          .setCustomId("verificationModal")
          .setTitle("");

        // verified member role
        const verifiedMemberRole = interaction.guild.roles.cache.get("");

        // nickname text input
        const nicknameInput = new TextInputBuilder()
          .setCustomId("nicknameInput")
          .setLabel()
          .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short)
          .setPlaceholder()
          .setMaxLength(35)
          .setMinLength(7);

        // source text input
        const sourceInput = new TextInputBuilder()
          .setCustomId("sourceInput")
          .setLabel()
          .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Paragraph)
          .setPlaceholder()
          .setMaxLength(150)
          .setMinLength(10);

        // action rows
        const nicknameRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(nicknameInput);
        const sourceRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(sourceInput);
        verificationModal.addComponents(nicknameRow, sourceRow);

        // denied verification message
        const deniedVerificationMessage = new EmbedBuilder()
          .setTitle()
          .setDescription()
          .setColor(0xf08080)
          .setTimestamp()
          .setFooter({
            text: `${interaction.client.user.username}`, iconURL: `${interaction.client.user.avatarURL()}`,
          });

        // check if interaction.member is viable to show the modal
        if (interaction.member.roles.cache.has(verifiedMemberRole)) {
          interaction.reply({embeds: [deniedVerificationMessage], ephemeral: true})
        } else if (interaction.member.permissions.has(PermissionsBitField.Flags.ManageRoles) || interaction.member.permissions.has(PermissionsBitField.Flags.Administrator)) {
          interaction.reply({embeds: [deniedVerificationMessage], ephemeral: true})
        } else {
          interaction.showModal(verificationModal);
        }

        break;
      }
    }
  },
};
```

`verificationModalEvent.js` (here I'm working with a submit of the modal & sending text inputs' info to the channel)

```js
const {Events, EmbedBuilder, ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle} = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: Events.InteractionCreate, async execute(interaction) {
        if (!interaction.isModalSubmit()) return;

        switch (interaction.customId) {
            case "verificationModal": {
                // verified member role
                const verifiedMemberRole = interaction.guild.roles.cache.get("");

                // verification requests channel
                const verificationRequestsChannel = interaction.client.channels.cache.get("");

                // text inputs
                const memberNickname = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue("nicknameInput");
                const memberSource = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue("sourceInput");

                // message that is shown to the user when submitting the modal
                const requestedVerificationEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
                    .setTitle()
                    .setDescription()
                    .setColor(0xffffb9)
                    .setTimestamp()
                    .setFooter({
                        text: `${interaction.client.user.username}`, iconURL: `${interaction.client.user.avatarURL()}`,
                    });
                    
                // verification request sent to the channel (verificationRequestsChannel)
                const requestVerificationEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
                    .setTitle()
                    .setDescription()
                    .addFields(
                        {name: "", value: memberNickname, inline: true},
                        {name: "", value: memberSource, inline: true}
                    )
                    .setColor(0xffffb9)
                    .setTimestamp()
                    .setFooter({
                        text: `ID: ${interaction.member.user.id}`, iconURL: `${interaction.client.user.avatarURL()}`,
                    });

                // buttons for approving or denying user's verification
                const requestVerificationButtons = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
                    new ButtonBuilder()
                        .setCustomId("approveVerification")
                        .setLabel("Approve")
                        .setEmoji("✅")
                        .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Success),
                    new ButtonBuilder()
                        .setCustomId("denyVerification")
                        .setLabel("Deny")
                        .setEmoji("❎")
                        .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Danger)
                )

                await verificationRequestsChannel.send({
                    embeds: [requestVerificationEmbed],
                    components: [requestVerificationButtons]
                })

                // await interaction.member.setNickname(memberNickname);
                await interaction.reply({
                    embeds: [requestedVerificationEmbed], ephemeral: true
                })

                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the question is how to work with new interactions of buttons (approveVerification & denyVerification) by also using the old author that submits the modal? Maybe I've done my so called 'verification system' completely wrong, not avoiding that possibility, but also keen on learning my mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written a similar system in the past for a role application system. I just added the user's @ into the `author` field of the embed, and then used `message.embeds[0].author` to read it later.

I can't test this right now, but [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53201455/how-to-get-discord-bot-to-read-embed) another answer that might help.

Comment: Yeah, it helped. I will post the solution below. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by passing the `interaction.member.user.id` to the embed sent to the verification channel like so:

`verificationModalEvent.js`

```
// request verification embed
const requestVerificationEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setTitle(``)
    .setDescription(``)
    .addFields({}, {})
    .setColor(0xffffb9)
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter({
        text: `${interaction.member.user.id}`, <—— *this is where I get the user ID*
        iconURL: interaction.member.user.displayAvatarURL()
    });
```

Then in the file `verificationCheckEvent.js` I obtain the id from the embed and the message object it's in:

`verificationCheckEvent.js`

```
const userId = interaction.message.embeds[0].data.footer.text;
```